# When is the user process's page table first updated during the program start stage

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, page-tables

I am recently studying Linux kernel and I have a question regarding how user process's page table is first updated by the kernel. Let's consider X86 architecture as an example.

1. When a binary is first started, it's handled by a structure called `bprm`. The main function for handling it is called: `do_execve`. In this function, `mm_struct` is created for the process which will create the top level page table `pgd`.
2. Then kernel will go ahead and create virtual spaces for the process and map each segment into the virtual space by `elf_map` function which will eventually call into `do_mmap()`
3. Then what I found is that, after all the preparation above, the kernel will call `START_THREAD` to start the process.

My question is that, before `START_THREAD`, there seems no where to initialize the page table of the process. Then after searched for a while, I found out that page table is updated only when needed which I assume that only during first read/write operation from the userspace, the page table entry is first updated(please correct me if I am wrong).

My question is where in the kernel does the first page table updates(if you can tell me the code location that would be better)?

Comment: The kernel probably uses demand paging. It will modify the page tables when needed on page fault. You should look in the page fault handler.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking not about the first *update*, but initial creation.  I think modern Linux isn't fully lazy and creates an initial page table with at least a stack page and a page containing the entry point already wired into the HW page tables, instead of letting the HW cause a page fault before doing anything.  (This is an optimization; I think I read that very early Linux did just set up the virtual mapping and let it rip, when virtual memory support was first written in 0.something).  I don't know which function that happens in, though.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is: **yes, modern kernel does employ a lazy allocation for page tables**.

Before identify the code location, let's check how this happens. The common path here is:
You do mmap to create a new vma(virtual memory area) -> kernel reserves the virtual memory range on your process address space -> After return to userspace, you try to access(read/write) the mmap region -> As the physical page has not been allocated, this triggers a page fault to allocate the physical page -> After some hardware context saving and trap prologues, you arrive at the architecture-specific page fault handler -> Before allocating the physical page, kernel has to make sure the page table itself is allocated. **This is where the lazy page table allocation happens.**

In general, the stack/heap of a userspace process is each described by a vma(just like the normal mmap region), so the above path also applies to your question.

Code location(source code version on my workspace is 5.13.2) for x86 can be found under `arch/x86/mm/fault.c`(as mentioned above, page fault handling is highly architecture-dependent). The call-chain can be traced with `handle_page_fault()` -> `do_user_addr_fault()` -> `handle_mm_fault()`(goto `mm/memory.c`) -> `__handle_mm_fault()`

Within `mm/memory.c/__handle_mm_fault()`, you will find code snippet like this:

```
    struct vm_fault vmf = {
        .vma = vma,
        .address = address & PAGE_MASK,
        .flags = flags,
        .pgoff = linear_page_index(vma, address),
        .gfp_mask = __get_fault_gfp_mask(vma),
    };
    unsigned int dirty = flags & FAULT_FLAG_WRITE;
    struct mm_struct *mm = vma->vm_mm;
    pgd_t *pgd;
    p4d_t *p4d;
    vm_fault_t ret;

    pgd = pgd_offset(mm, address);
    p4d = p4d_alloc(mm, pgd, address);
    if (!p4d)
        return VM_FAULT_OOM;

    vmf.pud = pud_alloc(mm, p4d, address);
    if (!vmf.pud)
        return VM_FAULT_OOM;

        ...

    vmf.pmd = pmd_alloc(mm, vmf.pud, address);
    if (!vmf.pmd)
        return VM_FAULT_OOM;

        ...

    return handle_pte_fault(&vmf);
```

Modern linux uses four/five level page table on 64-bit machine, lazy page table allocation is necessary to reduce memory usage.